# Wicked PDF changing font-size and font-family in Rails Production

Tags: wicked-pdf

Why **wicked_pdf** renders different in Rails environment (development & production) font-size and font-family changes.

I'm using Amazon EC2 Linux as production environment.

Even I already set the font-size & font-family in CSS.

How to make or set it to have consistent display of data.

Please help!

Comment: Its late, but usualy this kind of issues happen when you have different version of wicked pdf. check for the version and make sure you use same version for development and on production

Comment: Hi @Deepak, I have the same version for 2 environment. I already fixed it by importing my local System fonts to EC2 Server

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED**

I fixed it by:

**First:** Importing my local system fonts to EC2 Serverm, using **scp**.

***Note***: Make sure to back up first.

**Secondly:**
I found a solution also here in stack, to use and import fonts.

**In you applicantion directory**:

```
mkdir fonts
  > add the fonts you will use, in my case Arial

cd fonts
mkdir .ebextensions
vi copy_fonts.config
  > put the code below:

  container_commands:
    copy_fonts:
      command: "cp fonts/*.ttf /usr/share/fonts/"
```

I hope this will help others who encountered the same issue.